# Local Unit Test - Asynchronous Requests Calling High Replication Datastore

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine

I've been developing a python application on app engine using Test Driven Development. One of the tests I've written does 2 HTTP requests to the local server (simulating a normal behavior of the application). The first requests generates a database entity and returns some ID I'm assigning to it on the server and the second requests send the ID it got with other data to update the first record.
My problem is that trying to run the server using the --high_replication (Simulating the High Replication Datastore) on the second request the server cannot find the ID in the datastore yet. (Without the --high_replication it's working).
I've found a work-around for this with adding sleep between each request but I'm sure there is a better way.

Any information or help will be very much thankful.

To provide some more information this is a part of the test:

```
response = self.sendPing()
response = self.updatePing(response['response'])
self.assertEquals(response['response'], 'OK')
```

The workaround i found for this is:

```
response = self.sendPing()
time.sleep(1)
response = self.updatePing(response['response'])
self.assertEquals(response['response'], 'OK')
```

When sleeping for 1 second between the requests I get a good result

kodkod

Comment: Not sure with the information provided, but it sounds like either your unit tests are testing more than a single unit. Or your units are doing too much. Ideally you want to test the HTTP code and the code that handles the ids separately.

Comment: Take a look at the post I've added some part of the test

Comment: This is actually quite accurate to how the live App Engine HRD environment *might* perform. If requests 1 and 2 hit different App Engine instances (call them A and B), there's no guarantee the entity created by request 1 will have been replicated to instance B by the time request 2 arrives. That said, I'm surprised this happens in the local environment as I was under the impression it was single threaded.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided doesn't tell me much about how you are querying for the data.

From purely theoretical perspective, you have several options here:

1. Use the key of the entity created and return the key in the response and then use the key to get the record. Eventual consistency does not apply to gets by keys.
2. Use named keys. [Please see answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271103/ndb-using-users-api-to-form-an-entity-group).
3. [Use Ancestor queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#ancestor). They are always consistent.

Answer (score 0):

When you use --high_replication, the datastore simulates eventual consistency behavior.

As Sologoub mentioned, you can make proper fully-consistent datastore calls to get proper reads.

Another option is to force the dev_appserver datastore to behave in a fully consistent manner.  You might want to use this to simplify certain tests, but keep in mind that it's not simulating real world consistency behavior.

See the documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Writing_HRD_Datastore_Tests

You want to set PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy to 100

Comment: This seems like a dangerous advice to give - if the dev environment is manipulated, it means this may break in production. This simulation exists for a reason.

Comment: I'd agree with you, but keep in mind that the API for setting the datastore consistency model also exists for a reason, and furthermore, dev_appserver for runs in a fully consistent mode by default.  One way or the other, the developer's gotta know what he's doing.