# How to query entities by ID

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to query entities by their ID, but excluding their parent ID.

Here's some code to help explain:

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    ...

class User(ndb.Model):
    ...
class Review(ndb.Model):
    ...
```

When I create `Review` objects, I set their parent to be the user, and their ID to be the same as the book ID:

```
review = Review(key=ndb.Key('Review', book.key.id(), parent=user.key))
```

Now I'd like to know how many reviews there are for each book, by doing a query. Querying by a complete key wouldn't work as the parent IDs will be different.

The workaround I currently use is storing the book ID in a `ndb.KeyProperty` or `ndb.IntegerProperty`, but that is effectively redundant information as the ID of the review will already be the same.

Is there any way to do a query by only the key ID, excluding the parent ID?

Comment: I don't hting that there is an official way. Storing a reference property is a good idea and you can get the book reviews like: 
book.reviews. Also why do you set the parent as the user and not the book ? If you wanted to delete a book and all it's reviews how would you do it then ?

Comment: @JimmyKane The book-review example was just a stripped-down version of what I'm doing; I need the parent-child relation to be like this because my app is editing a lot of "reviews" in one transaction, so it needs to lock a user's entity group for that to work.

Comment: Lock the user's entity group eg for being sure that the user is not deleted or something like that?

Comment: Why are there XG transcanctions ? You get never get the entity by ID only if there is a parent. You need the parent key or then you can just post the entity key. Your choice

Comment: @JimmyKane XG transactions don't work for more than 5 entity groups, or at least not well, last time I tried it was significantly slower than a single-group transaction. Also the datastore will update all the reviews in one API call as long as I keep them in one entity group.

Comment: Of course, I think you need a bit resign in you models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>You'd use something like this to query by ID: `review = Review.get_by_id(book.key.id())`.</del>

Your approach of setting the ID only works if there is a 1 to 1 relationship between a book and a review, as Keys are unique. The above operation will only return one entity.

I'd recommend setting the most used query as the Ancestor for the review. My guess is that he Book the review belongs to is the most relevant here, unless your users are famous critics.

If you set the Review's parent as the Book, you can use [Ancestor queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#ancestor) to get all of the reviews with guaranteed consistency. Then user can be a property of the review and you could simply filter by that property. I'd suggest using KeyProperty for the reference.

If you want guaranteed consistency for the queries by user, keep a list of reviewed books for each user (repeated KeyProperty), and then run ancestor queries against the reviews, filtered by that user.

UPDATE:
 @JimmyKane is right - the get_by_id won't work at all because it apparently requires the parent to be specified, and in your case that doesn't seem very practical.

Code that proves that the get_by_id won't work:

```
from flask import Flask

from google.appengine.ext import ndb

app = Flask(__name__)

class User(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Book(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Review(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

@app.route('/')
def hello_main():
    user = User()
    user.name = 'Test User1'
    user.put()

    book = Book()
    book.name = 'Test Book1'
    book.put()

    review = Review(id=book.key.id(), parent=user.key)
    review.name = 'Test Review1'
    review.put()

    return 'Review saved!'

@app.route('/reviews/')
def reviews():
    book = Book.query(Book.name == 'Test Book1').get()
    user = User.query(User.name == 'Test User1').get()

    if book:
        review = Review.get_by_id(book.key.id(), parent=user.key)
        if review:
            return review.name
        else:
            return 'no review'
    else:
        return 'no books'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And here's sample code for my recommended approach:

```
from flask import Flask

from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class User(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    reviews = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)

class Book(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Review(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_main():
    user = User()
    user.name = 'Test User1'
    user.put()

    book = Book()
    book.name = 'Test Book1'
    book.put()

    review = Review(parent=book.key)
    review.name = 'Test Review1'
    review.put()

    user.reviews.append(review.key)
    user.put()

    return 'Review saved!'

@app.route('/add_review/')
def add_review():
    book = Book.query(Book.name == 'Test Book1').get()
    user = User.query(User.name == 'Test User1').get()

    if book:
        review = Review(parent=book.key)
        review.name = 'Test Review'
        review.put()

        user.reviews.append(review.key)
        user.put()

        return 'review added'
    else:
        return 'no books'

@app.route('/reviews/')
def reviews():
    book = Book.query(Book.name == 'Test Book1').get()
    user = User.query(User.name == 'Test User1').get()

    if book:
        reviews = Review.query(ancestor=book.key)
        for review in reviews:
            print(review.name)
            print('<br/>')
        return ''
    else:
        return 'no books'


@app.route('/reviews_by_user/')
def reviews_by_user():
    user = User.query(User.name == 'Test User1').get()

    for review_key in user.reviews:
        review = review_key.get()
        print(review.name)
        print('<br/>')
    return ''



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Doesn't review = Review.get_by_id(book.key.id(), parent=None) ? 
It wont return anything...

Comment: @JimmyKane, not sure what you are asking... Could you please rephrase?

Comment: Doesn't the get_by_id method require a parent? If parent is not given None is implied. So at your example the get_by_id will return 0 results.

Comment: Don't think that's the case. Docs don't say anything about this requirement: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id. Also, I'm using example from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271103/ndb-using-users-api-to-form-an-entity-group

Comment: Look again. The **default** is None and also states:
Returns an entity by ID. This is really just a shorthand for Key(cls, id).get() Wich means that if you don't have the full path you cant get it if it's not a **Root** entity

Comment: No problem man. I run into the same problem just some hours ago. It was my barrier. Nevertheless you answer is correct, but he needs to set the parent to the book and a writer reference property for the review to the user.

Comment: This is a nice and thorough explanation, thank you for that. Unfortunately in my case I cannot change the parent-child relations. This was just a simplified example, imagine that my app is is editing reviews all the time, usually in a batch per user, so I need all the reviews of a user to be in the same entity group for that to make one nice transaction. The repeated key would be a good idea, but I'm afraid it wouldn't scale well, imagine a book with millions of reviews, storing even just the number of reviews would need to be sharded.